# Assign table alias name in a QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

How can I assign an alias name to the main table of a QuerySet in Django?

```
  queryset = Price.objects
  queryset = queryset.extra(
    where = ['p1.created = (select max(p2.created) from products_price p2 where p2.product_id = p1.product_id)']
  )
```

I would like to set the 'p1' alias name to the Price main table to use it in the subselect.

Edit: Note that there is a lastest Price for each Produtc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the sql query to do the next:

```
queryset = Price.objects.all()
print queryset.query
```

If you know first sql query. You can do the subquery better.

Although, I do the next:

```
price_max = Price.objects.all().order_by('-created')[0]
queryset = Price.objects.filter(created=price_max)
```

Or the best:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset

```
from django.db.models import Max
price_max = Price.objects.aggregate((Max('created'))['created__max']
queryset = Price.objects.filter(created=price_max)
```

Comment: I want to get the lastest Price (this is the max created) for each Product. That's why I used the subquery with the filter "where p2.product_id = p1.product_id". Is it possible to reproduce it with aggregate ?